# Numerically encoded message for a role playing game

Tags: riddle, cipher

I play a role-playing game set in a modern fantasy universe. When the Game Master cannot attend he likes to set us puzzles instead. If we can crack them we earn extra experience... we have never cracked a single one. If someone could help me solve one for a change I would be very appreciative! Below is all the information we have been given:

> While sleeping in the Dark Forest, Erin dreams of whispers, hearing Leonardo's voice, he wakes up frantically and begins scribbling numbers on a wall. Waking up the next day, you realize they seem to make little sense, but maybe Leonardo's trying to tell you something...
>
> ```
> 208519211720211391811229612101514221916220  
> 23713141763244158525616918723721  
> 8151016111425222111781223198171291026  
> 132723282421131892922251424111419152010252032616111230
> ```

Comment: At the beginning, `20 8 5`, are the positions of the letters `T H E` in the alphabet.  I can't get it to make a lot of sense beyond that, though.

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood what you wrote, GPR.  I have a different thought..

Comment: Yes, I noticed this but I can't seem to decipher another word. If I could just get one more word then I would be convinced that that was the way to work it out but as it stands I'm not entirely certain.

Comment: I don't think that is the pattern.  The last two characters are 30, so you would either have C and nothing, or a non-existent letter.

Comment: I've been trying to relate the numbers to indexes in the paragraph (including after removing all non-letters), but I'm currently coming up with nothing due to the sheer number of variations.  There's 271 characters before removing non-letters, and 216 after.

Comment: The repetition of the numbers seems important.  You'd rarely see a letter repeated three times, in sequence, yet there are 4 uses of 111 and 2 uses of 222.

Comment: Could 0 equate to being a full stop?

Comment: The sum of all digits on the four lines are 124, 127, 115 and 153 respectively. Looking at the ASCII table(extended ASCII for 153), I got the answer ```|DELsÖ```. Which is the stupidest answer of all time, unless.... do you have a place in your universe which has the name Delso?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. My Game Master has become over confident and has told me that " its an alphabet replacement...with a twist" He has also confirmed that the first word is indeed 'the' so I believe we are getting close! If you are translating and you come across a word you're not sure about try putting it in to the wiki http://scionprimarchs.wikia.com/wiki/Scion:_Rise_of_the_Primarchs_Wiki

Comment: Is there a language in Scion with an alphabet with more than 30 characters in it?

Comment: How 'evil' is your GM? "...we have never cracked a single one" Do you have proof that there *is* a solution to those ? Just asking because I know some very mean GMs ;-)

Comment: Is `815101` = `how`?

Comment: Will you tell your GM that you got assistance from out-of-world people?

Answer (score 1):

The first line goes to something like this:

> 20 8 5
>   T   H E
>
> 19
>   S/AI
>
> 2117
>   UQ/UAG/BAAG/BKG/BAQ
>
> 20
>   T
>
> 2113
>   UM/UAC/BKC/BAM/BAAC
>
> 9
>   I
>
> 18
>   R/AH
>
> 1122
>   KV/ALB/AAV/KBB/AABB
>
> 9
>   I
>
> 6
>   F
>
> 12
>   L/AB
>
> 10
>   J/A
>
> 15
>   O/AE
>
> 14
>   N/AD
>
> 2219
>   VS/VAI/BTI/BBS/BBAI
>
> 16
>   P/AF
>
> 220
>   BT/BB/V

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much help it is, but I got the frequency set, just to rule out some existing ciphers.

- `0`: 10
- `1`: 50
- `2`: 39
- `3`: 11
- `4`: 9
- `5`: 10
- `6`: 9
- `7`: 8
- `8`: 9
- `9`: 10

Comment: This digit frequency fits the profile of English text, enciphered with a polyalphabetic cipher (such as Vigenere), then encoded with A1Z26. It also fits the profile of uniformly random letters from A-Z encoded with A1Z26.